# Creating Objects for Game in C++

Tags: c++, object, pong

I'm working on coding a Pong game and am having trouble creating objects. I had working code, but it did not include a class or any objects, and since it is for an Object-Oriented Programming class, I needed to fix that. However, now I'm getting a bunch of different error messages (it stops displaying after 100). Most of them appear to be dealing with me not creating objects correctly.

I've never worked with objects in C++ (probably should've, but have just been muddling through this class and getting points deducted for this very reason), but since the semester is winding down, I really need to do well on this project.

**Update**
I've managed to get rid of the majority of the errors, but there are still a few remaining that have me stumped. I have edited my code to reflect the changes I've made and updated the error list.

Here is my code:

My header file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
//#include <gl\gl.h>
//#include <gl\glu.h>
#include "GL/freeglut.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Opengl32.lib")
#define VK_W 0x57
#define VK_S 0x53
using namespace std;

class Pong {
public:
    Pong();
    std::string int2str;
    void drawText(float x, float y, std::string text);
    void drawPaddle(float x, float y, float width, float height);
    void draw();
    void enable2D(int width, int height);
    void keyboard();
    void vec2_norm(float& x, float &y);
    void updateBall();
    void gameOverCheck();
    void update(int value);

    //window size and update rate
    int width;
    int height;
    int interval; // 60 frames per-second

    //scoring
    int p1Score; //Player 1's score
    int p2Score; //Player 2's score
    int winner;

    //the paddles
    int paddleWidth;
    int paddleHeight;
    int paddleSpeed;
    float paddleLeftX;
    float paddleLeftY;
    float paddleRightX;
    float paddleRightY;

    //the ball
    float ballPositionX; 
    float ballPositionY;
    float ballDirectionX;
    float ballDirectionY;
    int ballSize;
    int ballSpeed;
};
```

My .cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PongGame.h"
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
//#include <gl\gl.h>
//#include <gl\glu.h>
#include "GL/freeglut.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Opengl32.lib")
#define VK_W 0x57
#define VK_S 0x53
using namespace std;

Pong pong;
Pong::Pong() {
    width = 500;
    height = 300;
    interval = 1000/60;
    p1Score = 0;
    p2Score = 0;
    winner = 0;
    paddleWidth = 10;
    paddleHeight = 80;
    paddleSpeed = 3;
    paddleLeftX = 10.0f;
    paddleLeftY = 50.0f;
    paddleRightX = width - paddleWidth - 10;
    paddleRightY = 50;
    ballPositionX = width / 2;
    ballPositionY = height / 2;
    ballDirectionX = -1.0f;
    ballDirectionY = 0.0f;
    ballSize = 8;
    ballSpeed = 3;
}

std::string int2str(int x) { //used to convert an integer to a string
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << x;

    return ss.str( );
}

void drawText(float x, float y, std::string text) {
    glRasterPos2f(x, y);
    glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, (const unsigned char*)text.c_str());
}

void drawPaddle(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        glVertex2f(x + width, y);
        glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
        glVertex2f(x, y + height);
    glEnd();
}

void draw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //draws the paddles
    drawPaddle(pong.paddleLeftX, pong.paddleLeftY, pong.paddleWidth, pong.paddleHeight);
    drawPaddle(pong.paddleRightX, pong.paddleRightY, pong.paddleWidth, pong.paddleHeight);

    //draws the ball
    drawPaddle(pong.ballPositionX - pong.ballSize / 2, pong.ballPositionY- pong.ballSize / 2, pong.ballSize, pong.ballSize);

    //draws the score at the top center of the screen
    drawText(pong.width / 2 - 10, pong.height - 15, int2str(pong.p1Score) + ":" + int2str(pong.p2Score));

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void enable2D(int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void keyboard() { //allows teh paddles to be controled from the keyboard
    //moves left paddle (player 1)
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_W))
        pong.paddleLeftY += pong.paddleSpeed; //move paddle up with "W" key

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_S)) 
        pong.paddleLeftY -= pong.paddleSpeed; //move paddle down with "S" key

    //moves right paddle (player 2)
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)) 
        pong.paddleRightY += pong.paddleSpeed; //move paddle up with "up" arrow

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)) 
        pong.paddleRightY -= pong.paddleSpeed; //move paddle down with "down" arrow
}

void vec2_norm(float& x, float &y) {
    float length = sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));

    if(length != 0.0f) {
        length = 1.0f / length;
        x *= length;
        y *= length;
    }
}

void updateBall() { //allows teh ball to move
    pong.ballPositionX += pong.ballDirectionX * pong.ballSpeed;
    pong.ballPositionY += pong.ballDirectionY * pong.ballSpeed;

    if(pong.ballPositionX < pong.paddleLeftX + pong.paddleWidth && pong.ballPositionX > pong.paddleLeftX && pong.ballPositionY < pong.paddleLeftY + pong.paddleHeight && pong.ballPositionY > pong.paddleLeftY) { //if ball is hit by player 1's paddle
        float t = ((pong.ballPositionY - pong.paddleLeftY) / pong.paddleHeight) - 0.5f;
        pong.ballDirectionX = fabs(pong.ballDirectionX); 
        pong.ballDirectionY = t;
    }

    if (pong.ballPositionX > pong.paddleRightX && pong.ballPositionX < pong.paddleRightX + pong.paddleWidth && pong.ballPositionY < pong.paddleRightY + pong.paddleHeight && pong.ballPositionY > pong.paddleRightY) { //if ball is hit by player 2's paddle
        float t = ((pong.ballPositionY - pong.paddleRightY) / pong.paddleHeight) - 0.5f;
        pong.ballDirectionX = -fabs(pong.ballDirectionX); 
        pong.ballDirectionY = t;
    }

    if (pong.ballPositionX < 0) { //if ball hits the top wall
        ++pong.p2Score;
        pong.ballPositionX = pong.width / 2;
        pong.ballPositionY = pong.height / 2;
        pong.ballDirectionX = fabs(pong.ballDirectionX); 
        pong.ballDirectionY = 0;
    }

    if (pong.ballPositionX > pong.width) { //if ball hits the right wall
        ++pong.p1Score;
        pong.ballPositionX = pong.width / 2;
        pong.ballPositionY = pong.height / 2;
        pong.ballDirectionX = -fabs(pong.ballDirectionX); 
        pong.ballDirectionY = 0;
    }

    if (pong.ballPositionY > pong.height) { //ball hits top wall
        pong.ballDirectionY = -fabs(pong.ballDirectionY); 
    }

    if (pong.ballPositionY < 0) { //ball hits bottom wall
        pong.ballDirectionY = fabs(pong.ballDirectionY); 
    }

    vec2_norm(pong.ballDirectionX, pong.ballDirectionY);
}

void gameOverCheck() {
    const int maxScore = 10;
    if(pong.p1Score == maxScore) {
        cout << "Player 1 Wins!" << endl;
        pong.winner = 1;
    }
    else if(pong.p2Score == maxScore) {
        cout << "Player 2 Wins!" << endl;
        pong.winner = 2;
    }
}

void update(int value) {
   keyboard();

   if(pong.winner == 0) {
        updateBall();
        glutTimerFunc(pong.interval, update, 0);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        gameOverCheck();
    }
}
```

My main file:

```
//PongGameTest.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PongGame.h"
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
//#include <gl\gl.h>
//#include <gl\glu.h>
#include "GL/freeglut.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Opengl32.lib")
#define VK_W 0x57
#define VK_S 0x53
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("Pong");

    glutDisplayFunc(pong.draw);
    glutTimerFunc(pong.interval, pong.update, 0);

    pong.enable2D(pong..width, pong.height);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

And I'm sure y'all will hate me for this, but here are the errors I'm getting when I compile:

```
1>  PongGameTest.cpp
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(25): error C2065: 'pong' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(25): error C2228: left of '.draw' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(26): error C2065: 'pong' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(26): error C2228: left of '.interval' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(26): error C2065: 'pong' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(26): error C2228: left of '.update' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(28): error C2065: 'pong' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(28): error C2228: left of '.enable2D' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(28): error C2065: 'pong' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(28): error C2059: syntax error : '.'
1>c:\users\hitechredneck\desktop\fall 2014\object-oriented programming\game\ponggame\ponggame\ponggametest.cpp(29): error C2228: left of '.glColor3f' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
```

I'm well aware that nobody is going to read all of those messages (I know I sure wouldn't) but could you possibly skim them and see if you might can figure out what I'm doing wrong? Like I said, I'm almost 100% sure that many of them have to do with me not creating the object correctly and using it's members properly.

Comment: Could you cut down the code, to the important part?

Comment: The last set of messages with ; (semicolon) missing thing are all because you didn't terminate your statements with semicolon in ponggame.cpp file - change them first (easy). Also, you are trying to access your class member functions/variables that are declared private (in your ponggame.cpp file). Keep the member variables private and the access methods public - simple OO design constraints.

Comment: Just wrapping all your code in one class won't help your grades much. You'll need to review the rest of the course until you get the point.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions I was able to clear several of the errors, but am still left with a lot of "undeclared identifier" errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I know @molbdnilo, it's just that this is due tomorrow so am trying to get as much done as I can. We had to turn in a pre-release which I got an 80 on, even though I didn't even use a class, so am hoping that I can get somewhat close to that if I even use a single class.

Answer (score 6):

1.

```
Pong Pong;
```

is illegal: you can't declare an object with a type name as identifier. This could've been `Pong pong`.

2.

```
Pong::enable2D()
```

is illegal: `enable2D` isn't a static function, but a member (per-instance) function and thus you've to call it via an object, like `pong.enable2D();`.

3.

```
extern Pong pong;  // in the header
Pong pong;         // and both of these in the source
Pong Pong;
```

This is definitely wrong. What are you trying to do? Global or not, you can't declare an object named `Pong` of type `Pong` as explained above (1). Also you perhaps don't want a global but just an automatic variable in the `main` function.

### Errors

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'

If the compiler doesn't have the declaration of an identifier that it'll be unable to accept the token `.` and will be expecting a `;` instead.

> error C2248: 'Pong::height' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Pong'

This is as clear as C++ compiler errors get to be.

Please read [a good C++ beginner book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and get such logistical issues out of your way. Internet is not a good teacher, it's a good reference library, but it can't replace a good book mostly.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm mostly just left with some "undeclared identifier" errors that I've gotta figure out how to get rid of.

Comment: In point 2., I am sure you meant `enable2D()` instead of `enable2()`

Comment: @HiTechRedneck3 Welcome to StackOverflow! If the answer is helpful for you, you can "accpet" it by clicking 'check button', which is next to the body of the answer.

Comment: All of my errors seem to concentrated around lines 25-28 in my PongGameTest file, but I can't figure out how to correct them.

Comment: The compiler is unable to see the variable `pong`. You should do `Pong pong;` inside the `main` function.

Comment: I did this and am now only left with one error at the line that reads "glutTimerFunc(pong.interval, pong.update, 0);" in my PongGameTest file. The specific error is occurring on the "." in "pong.update". Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't `update` a function? How do you call a function? What you're doing is referring to it like a variable.

Comment: I've tried calling it several different ways, but keep getting errors, I know in my definition of update() it's passed an int value, but not sure what needs to be passed to it here...